# script with python to verify apache status

Tags: python, linux, apache2

I need to make a script that checks if apache2 is working, if yes, it gives a confirmation message, if not, it starts apache2, the problem is that my script has an error when apache needs to be started, but it works when apache2 it's already started.

This is for a linux server, just to start apache, but i'm new on that

```
    services = ['apache2']
    for service in services:
            status = subprocess.check_output("/etc/init.d/"+service+" status", shell=True)
            if ("is stopped" in status):
                    print service + "  - Stopped"
                    print service + "  - Trying to start"
                    service_start = subprocess.check_output("/etc/init.d/"+service+" start", shell=True)
            else:
                    print service + "  - Running "
```

The error message is:

```
status = subprocess.check_output("/etc/init.d/"+service+" status", shell=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 223, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/etc/init.d/apache2 status' returned non-zero exit status 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_output` raises an exception when the process return value is other than 0, you need to wrap the call with a try except statement

```
import subprocess

services = ['apache2']
for service in services:
    try:
        status = subprocess.check_output("/etc/init.d/"+service+" status", shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        status = "is stopped"

        if ("is stopped" in status):
                print service + "  - Stopped"
                print service + "  - Trying to start"
                service_start = subprocess.check_output("/etc/init.d/"+service+" start", shell=True)
        else:
                print service + "  - Running "
```